# upload file to ec2 instance in fedora

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a ec2 instance and I want to upload file into it. I did it this way:
I found the public DNS from the AWS management console.
Then I ran the `scp` command and got this .

```
    scp  -v  helloworld.java ec2-user@ec2-204-236-198-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host ec2-204-236-198-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com, user ec2-user, command scp -v -t -- /home
OpenSSH_5.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0d-fips 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-204-236-198-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com [204.236.198.218] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dassio/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dassio/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dassio/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dassio/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-204-236-198-218.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dassio/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dassio/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dassio/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: If you edit questions, please only add new information or fix incorrect data, do not completely re-write the question. Your edit completely changed the question, and now the answer which was previously relevant appears to have no relevance to the problem. That is bad etiquette on a site like this. You can update with new developments, but there should either be an understandable progression or switch to a new question for a new problem.

Comment: sorry this time, i shall keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ip address you are using is an internal network address that can only be reached from inside the EC2 availability zone.

You need to use the external address to reach the instance. You can find this using `ec2-describe-instances`. The address will likely be something like ec2.x-x-x-x.blah.amazonaws.com.

Additionally, although since you seem to already be in on the command line you might have already done this, you might need to allow access to port 22 through the EC2 firewall to your instance.

Comment: i changed the ip , but still it is not working , is it right that i use the public DNS?(i changed the problem above )

Comment: Your problem is morphing here. The answer above was correct for your original problem, but your current edit shows an entirely different problem. You now have an authentication issue. Your instance wants to authorize you via a key based system, and your scp isn't offering any credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Caleb is right. i have to offer some credentials to amazon . the Syntax is like:
`scp -i YOUR_KEY_PAIR FILE_WANT_TO_UPLOAD ec2-user@ec2.x-x-x-x.blah.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user`
you can't upload to the home directory(i guess because you are using the ec2-user name).

```
ec2.x-x-x-x.blah.amazonaws.com
```

is what Caleb mentioned as the external address. what i did in my original questions is i got the internal address from the `ifconfig` command. sorry again for messing up the question.